# File manager for Linux that organizes files on a mind map structure?

Tags: linux, web-apps, file-management, data-visualization

I'm looking for a file manager that allows me to visualize the local files from my computer on a mind map structure. The idea of the map would be something like this:

[image]

This GIF is from a [beta extension from TiddlyWiki](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/TiddlyWikiDev/KEImPODsLHA) and it's not exactly a file manager, I used it just to represent the idea. The key characteristics I'm looking for are:

1. A file manager application that allows me to visualize the files of my computer on a two-dimensional tree structure.
2. The possibility of inserting icons to represent my files.
3. It allows me to change files location with a drag-and-drop feature.
4. Runs on Linux (I'm fine with web applications too).

Does anyone know if such software exists?

Comment: Baobab has a graphic representation of files, but no managing AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

TheBrain has an older version that has been tested on Ubuntu.
http://old.thebrain.com/products/thebrain/download-8/
Select Linux/Unix on the "Choose your operating system" dropdown.

Comment: It's cool the functionality of always centralizing the branches we're navigating. But that's not exactly what I'm looking for... I was thinking more about something where we can see the big picture of the files. TheBrain allows us to see only two layers of the map.